# Question about width of a <header> header

Tags: css

1. I use a  element as the header of my webpage,i want the header to run the full length of my webpage width so I left the width of the header to default(100%),the question is that when I scroll the webpage horizontally,the header's width is auto-adjusted to fit the screen,but I want the header to fit the document width,not the screen width,I mean it does not shrink,any idea how to do it,here is an example that shows the effect I want:
   jquery.com
   you can try scroll it horizontally and see the header does not shrink...

(of course I can not set it to a fixed value because that will cause the header can not run the full length in some resolutions).

Comment: We need to see some CSS and/or HTML markup. We can't help you blindfolded.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wpqDy/ Basically you se the header background for example in your html or body.

Note that my example was older one ive used before.

You should use background in `html` first and then `body` if youre using 2 background images.

Like this for just single bg image `background: #333 url("bg_top.jpg") repeat-x top left`

If you then continue to build the website with a wrapper and so on you will restrict everything with that. Example of all that.. http://www.jsfiddle.net/wpqDy/3

Comment: but it still shrinks?? how to stop the header from shrinking when scrolling?

Comment: @liao24hoho I'm not sure what you mean with shrinking and scrolling.. Maybe this will explain? http://jsfiddle.net/wpqDy/3/